# Persistent UDP sessions on Android

Tags: android, udp

I have a client-server app which requires me to maintain a persistent session over UDP.

The goal is to maintain a path from the server to the mobile Android device no matter what route it has to the internet (WiFi or mobile network).

I need the phone to be able to maintain, say, a five-minute keep-alive with the server *at all times*. Ideally I would like to do this without maintaining any wake-locks on the device. I don't want the screen to light up every time I send a UDP to the server, for example, and I don't want to have a damaging effect on battery usage.

Has anyone addressed this problem?

Comment: According to your sentence "This is achieved using a proprietary, well-tested session-management protocol over UDP." you already have such a MobileIP-like solution - then I don't understand what is your actual question.

Comment: @Robert, absolutely right, that line does confuse matters. The protocol design itself is not the problem, the problem is that it relies on being able to talk to the session management gateway in order to work. I'll update the question accordingly.